# Getting a list of values of a column depending on the conditions of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

For the given dataframe `df` as:

```
       Election Yr.  Party   Region Votes
   0     2000           A       a    50  
   1     2000           A       b    30
   2     2000           B       a    40
   3     2000           B       b    50  
   4     2000           C       a    30
   5     2000           C       c    40
   6     2004           A       a    20  
   7     2004           A       b    30
   8     2004           B       a    40
   9     2004           B       b    50  
   10    2004           C       a    60
   11    2004           C       b    40
   12    2008           A       a    30  
   13    2008           A       c    30
   14    2008           B       a    80
   15    2008           B       b    50  
   16    2008           C       a    60
   17    2008           C       b    40
```

How to find the list of regions which has a different winner in every election. The winner is decided by the total votes by a party in a year.

Comment: No, there is no output in the above case. This is just a representation of the actual dataframe. There is more number of regions and years. I just need to know how to get the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to figure out the winner in every election for each region, essentially the party with the highest vote.

`winners = df.groupby(['Election Yr.', 'Region']).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Party').Votes.idxmax())`

Then you can figure out for each region how many different winners there have been:

`n_unique_winners = winners.groupby(['Region']).nunique()`

You can also figure out how many elections have occurred in each region:

`n_elections = winners.groupby(['Region']).size()`

Entries with a true value in `n_unique_winners == n_elections` are the regions you are looking for.

To get a list of these regions, you can do `n_unique_winners[n_unique_winners == n_elections].index.values`

Comment: I assume that "regions which has a different winner in every election" means regions with at least two different winners across all years, which means the number of unique winners must be greater than 1.

Comment: Actually, every year there should be different winners. No two winners should be the same for any two years. What should be the condition for this case?

Comment: This is giving boolean results (True/False) for a region. How can I get the list of regions with boolean to be True. I am sorry for asking even a basic question as I am just a new learner.

Comment: How can I check the list of regions which are won by the same party every year?

Comment: In that case it's simple. You'd just do ``n_unique_winners[n_unique_winners == 1]``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233574/discussion-between-deepak-and-xyzjayne).